# Trouble applying CSS changes to dynamically created via JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to alter the size of my ".square" divs that are created using JS/JQuery. I've successfully changed the size of the container div, but using the exact same code does not work for the dynamically created .square divs, despite being able to apply events the .square divs in other ways.
I've been trying to understand the problem for the last two days, and have been writing and rewriting solutions, but I think my current skills are overlooking a very simple answer.

The aim was to have the .square divs' size be determined by how many squares will be in the container. The more squares, the smaller the .square div css.

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var create = function(king) {
        return $("#container").prepend("<div class='square' id=king></div>");
      }

      var sLoad = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
          $("#16").click(function() {
            $("#container").prepend("<div class='square'></div>");
          });
        };
      };
      sLoad();

      $("#clear").on("click", function() {
        $(".square").remove();
        num = prompt("How many squares would you like?");
        //  var containerSize = function(){
        //   var siz = 112 * num;
        //   $("#container").css({"height": siz+15+"px" , "width": siz+"px"});
        //  }
        //  containerSize()
        $(".square").css({
          "height": "50px",
          "width": "50px"
        });
        var make = function(num) {
          return num * num;
        };
        //var squareSize = function(){
        // var sqr = 600 / make(num);
        // $(".square").css({"height":sqr+"px" , "width":sqr+"px"});
        //};
        //squareSize();

        for (i = 0; i < make(num); i++) {
          $("#container").prepend("<div class='square'></div>");
        };
      });
      // $(".button").click(function(){
      //  

      //making the square dis and reappear
      $("#container").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0);
          }),
          $(".square").mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
          });
      });
    });
```

```css
#menuContainer {
  height: 45px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px blue dotted;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
#controlDiv {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50%;
  background-color: black;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px black dashed;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button {
  height: 27px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: solid 1px yellow;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div class="button" id="16">Click</div>
    <div class="button" id="clear">Clear</div>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <!-- <div id="controlDiv"></div> -->
  </div>

  <!--<div class="square"></div>-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. I have created a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/x0x9rv30/).

Comment: @user2181397 for the code to work you need to load the JQ library in jsfiddle

Comment: Here's the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/x0x9rv30/1/

Comment: I have created a template from the given code and added to the question to make it more interactive. In the example I am using jQuery 2.1.1, but if your version of jQuery is different, let me know so I can fix it !

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Masonry or Isotope? Another thing you can try is to simply add a class to your square to change it and have that compound class ready to go in your css, then there's no question if the change is in the DOM, it will just be there waiting to be used.

Comment: I think I found the problem, you apply the CSS on an non existing element : first you remove `square`, then you apply the css style on `square` (which shouldn't work because square doesn't exist) and then you add it.

Comment: Hey guys, I've just rearranged the code blocks in my text editor, and it's working. I can't believe it was something so simple. I also can't believe how quickly you guys move lol.

Thanks for the help.
Mihai, and Flame_Phoenix: I'm using the latest JQ so it should be fine. I've also realised that I should do this Jfiddle thing what asking a question. Thanks.
Pascal: I'm not using Masonry or Isotope, because I have no idea what they are lol. I'm still super new, but I'll look into these things.

Again, thank you all so so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiddle should work : https://jsfiddle.net/x0x9rv30/2/

You applied the CSS on removed elements, you need to create the elements first, then you can apply CSS on it.

I just swapped two code blocks :

**Before**

```
$(".square").remove();

$(".square").css({"height":"50px" , "width": "50px"});

for (i = 0; i < make(num); i++){            
    $("#container").prepend("<div class='square'></div>");
};
```

**After**

```
$(".square").remove();

for (i = 0; i < make(num); i++){            
    $("#container").prepend("<div class='square'></div>");
};

$(".square").css({"height":"50px" , "width": "50px"});
```